# How to write new info to JSON file in Tizen Studio

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, tizen, tizen-web-app

I want to write new info to existing JSON file in Tizen project (for mobile). I found that it is not possible without PHP (or Node.js) and Tizen doesn't support PHP.  Is there a way to send new data to JSON without PHP (and without creating local db)?

Comment: All you need is https://developer.tizen.org/community/code-snippet/web-code-snippet/readwrite-file

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It's possible with the Use of Tizen FileSystem API and JSON.parse() & JSON.stringify(). [ As [Chris G](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5734311/chris-g) Stated on Comment]

```
var res,file,text,jsonInit,obj,jsonString;

function createFile(){
    tizen.filesystem.resolve("documents", function(dir) {
        res = dir.createDirectory("res");
        file = res.createFile("data.json");

        file.openStream(
                "w",
                function(fs) {
                    jsonInit = '{"data1":"a","data2":"b"}';
                    fs.write(jsonInit);
                    alert("JSON file Created");
                    fs.close();
                }, function(e) {
                    console.log("Error " + e.message);
                }, "UTF-8");
        });
    }
function addInfo(){ 
    tizen.filesystem.resolve("documents", function(dir) {
           file = dir.resolve("res/data.json");  
           file.openStream(
            "rw",
            function(fs) {
                text = fs.read(file.fileSize);               
                var obj  = JSON.parse(text);
                obj.data3 = 'c';
                jsonString =  JSON.stringify(obj);
                fs.position = 0;
                fs.write(jsonString);
                fs.close();
                alert("New Info added on data3 key");           
            }, function(e) {
                console.log("Error " + e.message);
            }, "UTF-8");
        });
    }

function readFromFile(){
    tizen.filesystem.resolve("documents", function(dir) 
            {
               var file = dir.resolve("res/data.json");
               file.openStream(
                    "r", 
                    function(fs) {
                        text = fs.read(file.fileSize);       
                        fs.close();
                        obj  = JSON.parse(text);
                        alert("Test read --> value on data2:" +obj.data2);
                        alert("Test read --> value on data3:" +obj.data3);
                    }, function(e) {
                        console.log("Error " + e.message);
                    }, "UTF-8");
            });
    }
```

Test Demonstration:

[image]

Check Out the Guides and API References for Implementation.

[FileSystem Guide](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/web-application/data-storage-and-management/file-system)

[FileSystem API References](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/web-application?redirect=/dev-guide/latest/org.tizen.web.apireference/html/device_api/mobile/tizen/filesystem.html)

Comment: It works but I want to write to existing file in Tizen Project. File has path like '././my_file.json'. I tried to change paths in code but it didn't work.

Comment: Where's the JSON File? On Project Dir of your application in Tizen-Studio? Or On FileSystem of Tizen Device? If on FileSystem of Tizen Mobile device than please share the directory path.

Comment: Oddly enough, it kept repeating the last } when reading the file causing me to have invalid JSON. My fix so far is to change:
`text = fs.read(file.fileSize);`  to `text = fs.read(file.fileSize - 1);`

 Though that feels like a dirty hack